# How do I know how much RAM can I upgrade my laptop?

Tags: upgrade, ram

I have a HP Pavilion laptop quite old (2008) which I would like to increase the RAM. Ideally I would like to have 8Gb but I have no idea how to check if hardware could support this extension.

These are the details of the laptop:

```
laptop
    description: Notebook
    product: HP Pavilion dv6700 (KW091EA#ABE) (KW091EA#ABE)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: Rev 1
    serial: CNF810542K
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=oem-specific chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV sku=KW091EA#ABE uuid=434E4638-3130-3534-324B-001E682DB86A

*-core
       description: Motherboard  
       product: 30D0
       vendor: Quanta
       physical id: 0
       version: 85.26
       serial: None2

     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: 0
          version: F.30
          date: 04/24/2008
          size: 101KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb agp smartbattery

     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-60
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile TL60
          slot: Socket S1
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 2GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv vmmcall cpufreq

***-memory:0**
          description: System memory
          physical id: 3
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        ***-bank:0**
             description: DIMM DDR2 Síncrono 667 MHz (1,5 ns)
             physical: 0
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        ***-bank:1**
             description: DIMM DDR2 667 MHz (1,5 ns)
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM 2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

Comment: Please post English outputs only. A single terminal command will use the English locale if you write `LANG=C ` before it. Example: `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` Running `LANG=C` as the whole command will temporarily set the language to English for all following commands in the current terminal window. (Always assuming that English is your fallback language, which usually is the default)

Comment: Personally, I'd first check `uname -p` . If it says x86_64, that means you got 64 bit system, therefore can go above 4 GB. Otherwise, you have 32-bit, which cannot go over 4 GB. Next, I'd suggest opening the laptop and check if RAM is soldered or not ( most likely not ). Finally determine what type of ram you  have and how many pins it has (eg I have DDR2, 200 pin). Search up online, and buy the ram you need

Comment: thanks @Serg, it is actually x86_64 and obviously it s not soldered :)

Answer (score 5):

Run in the terminal:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 16
```

That's what I got in my machine:

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

It means that I can upgrade up to 32 gb and there are 2 memory slots in my laptop.

Comment: damn I was hoping for a more better news, my laptop can only support upto 8gb :( Is there any limitation based on what os you are using?

Comment: RAM capacity depends on the motherboard.

Comment: @Muzaffar I wasn t expecting to get this:

# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.4 present.
Handle 0x000B, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
Location: System Board Or Motherboard
Use: System Memory
Error Correction Type: None
Maximum Capacity: 2 GB
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Number Of Devices: 2
'Cause my  laptop has actually 4gb RAM?

Comment: Check by using "free -m" command total amount of RAM being used.